# Access HttpApplicationState (Application["key"]) data from inside a class

Tags: asp.net

I have a .net application and a class in it. In that class, I need to access the HttpApplicationState and store some value there. In other words, this is what I need to do:

`Application["myKey"] = "value";`

How can I do this? Application is not available from my class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `HttpContext.Current.Application["key"]`.

Comment: wow that was actually a lot easier than I expected. Many thanks!